# Javascript how to display the amount of users based on which month they are created

Tags: javascript

I want to display the amount of users based on which month they are created. I got the following data as example:

```
[ 
  { name: 'user1', created: 'may' },
  { name: 'user2', created: 'may' },
  { name: 'user3', created: 'may' },
  { name: 'user4', created: 'may' },
  { name: 'user5', created: 'june' },
  { name: 'user6', created: 'june' },
  { name: 'user7', created: 'august' },
  { name: 'user8', created: 'august' },
  { name: 'user9', created: 'august' } 
]
```

what I want to achieve is to display them like this:

```
may: 4
june: 2
august: 3
```

How can I do that?

Comment: What have you tried so far? ...need pure javascript? ...or external libraries, such as JQuery, can be used? Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/unique-values-in-an-array for inspiration.

Comment: @MarcM I've just tried to loop through the data array but I'm kinda stuck since I have no clue how to achieve this. Pure javascript would be favorized. :-) I just need an idea how to...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `reduce()` and return object as result.

```js
var data = [{"name":"user1","created":"may"},{"name":"user2","created":"may"},{"name":"user3","created":"may"},{"name":"user4","created":"may"},{"name":"user5","created":"june"},{"name":"user6","created":"june"},{"name":"user7","created":"august"},{"name":"user8","created":"august"},{"name":"user9","created":"august"}]

var result = data.reduce(function(r, e) {
  return r[e.created] = (r[e.created] || 0) + 1, r
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: This is awesome! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think this will give you the idea:

```
const usersCreatedInMay = users.filter(u => u.created == 'may')
```

`usersCreatedInMay` will return `null` or an `array`. Just look at the length of it to learn how many users created in may.

```
usersCreatedInMay.length
```

You can loop through all months and calculate how many users created in each month.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something that goes in this direction, code may not work since it is not tested.

```
function extract(month, data) {
       return let result = data.filter((res)=>{
        return res.created === month;
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a pure javascript code you can use:-

```
var monthWithUsercount = {};

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    var num = a[i];
    monthWithUsercount[num.created] = monthWithUsercount[num.created] ? monthWithUsercount[num.created]+1 : 1;
}
//Here "a" is the array consisting months and users.

console.log(monthWithUsercount);
```

Here is the working fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/sajalsuraj/7nychnd2/

Cheers!!